# Appfactory does not work properly

Tags: wso2

I have installed the Appfactory 2.1.0 on an instance with standard.large flavor(VCPUs 4, RAM 8GB, Size 30GB) from HP Helion public cloud (Openstack IaaS)

the system was up and running

I sshed to the instance, go the 
/mnt/10.0.0.61/appfactory/wso2appfactory-2.0.0/bin, issued the command 
wso2server.sh --status, and got the following prompts

there were two problems:

1, Cannot locate '/mnt/10.0.0.61/appfactory/wso2appfactory-2.0.0/repository/conf/etc/hector-config.xml'

2, ERROR {org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapServer} -  ERR_171 Failed to bind an LDAP service (10,389) to the service registry.
java.net.BindException: Address already in use

please help 
thanks

-----------the prompt----------------

> JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /opt/java
>   CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /mnt/10.0.0.61/appfactory/wso2appfactory-2.0.0
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:24,619]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.dataaccess.internal.DataAccessServiceDSComponent} -  Cannot locate '/mnt/10.0.0.61/appfactory/wso2appfactory-2.0.0/repository/conf/etc/hector-config.xml'. Using the default configuration
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:24,712]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:24,714]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Linux 3.13.0-36-generic, amd64
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:24,714]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : /opt/jdk1.7.0_51/jre
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:24,714]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.7.0_51
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:24,714]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.51-b03,Oracle Corporation
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:24,714]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : /mnt/10.0.0.61/appfactory/wso2appfactory-2.0.0
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:24,714]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : /mnt/10.0.0.61/appfactory/wso2appfactory-2.0.0/tmp
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:24,715]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : root, en-US, Etc/UTC
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:24,828]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) is currently being used. To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:24,828]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  Swap Memory size (MB): 0 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2048
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:25,019]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder} -  Agent created !
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:25,110]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:25,626]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.configuration.LDAPConfigurationBuilder} -  KDC server is disabled.
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:25,933]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.DirectoryActivator} -  Initializing Directory Server with working directory /mnt/10.0.0.61/appfactory/wso2appfactory-2.0.0/repository/data/org.wso2.carbon.directory and port 10389
>   [2015-05-22 13:13:32,641] ERROR {org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapServer} -  ERR_171 Failed to bind an LDAP service (10,389) to the service registry.
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use
>     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
>     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
>     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
>     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
>     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>     at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.open(NioSocketAcceptor.java:251)
>     at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.open(NioSocketAcceptor.java:48)
>     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.registerHandles(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:523)
>     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.access$200(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:65)
>     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor$Acceptor.run(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:407)
>     at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Answer (score 0):

well, this might be a false alarm.

it disappeared when I reboot the instance, and  restart the appfactory by the following command

> ubuntu@puppet:~/setup-script$ sudo ./restart.sh